# How to Pregreplace {number}) with \n{number})

Tags: php, regex

How can i replace `{number})` with `\n{number})`

Say i have something like this

```
1) test string testing new string. 2) that is also a new string no new line. 3) here also no new lines.
```

The output should be something like this

```
1) test string testing new string.

2) that is also a new string no new line.

3) here also no new lines.
```

How can i do that with a regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$outputstring = preg_replace('/([0-9]+)\)/', "\n$1)", $inputstring);
```

Matches any set of digits followed by a literal `)`, replaces with a newline followed by those digits followed by a `)`.

If you want there to actually be a blank line in between like in your example output, you'd actually want to insert two newlines (since you need a newline to end the line with text, and then another to add the blank line). Just make it `\n\n` instead of `\n` in the second argument if such is the case.

Also note that this will add a newline at the beginning of the string if it starts with a numbered point, so you might want to trim the string afterwards if you don't want the leading newline.

Comment: I would think about using `PHP_EOL` instead of \n though :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<!\A|\n\n)(?=[0-9]+\))/m', '\n\n', $subject);
```

will do the same thing as Dav's solution but will also leave numbers at the start of the string alone (in this case `1)`). It will also leave numbers alone if there already are two linebreaks before them.

Answer (score 1):

User `preg_replace` Function

$str = "1) test string testing new string. 2) that is also a new string no new line. 3) here also no new lines.";

```
print preg_replace("/(\d+\))/","\n$1" , $str);
```